# How can I insert an XML inside another XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml

Let's say I have an XML document

```
<letter>
  <body>Hello</body>
</letter>
```

Now I want to wrap it inside inside a root element so that I can get the following XML

```
<envelope> 
  <letter>
    <body>Hello</body>
  </letter>
</envelope>
```

I tried something like this, but I'm getting HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR - An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. I also tried importNode() but that too fails.

```
Document d1 = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(letterXml)));

Document d2 = builder.newDocument();
Element envelope = d2.createElement("envelope");
d2.appendChild(envelope);

NodeList nodes = d1.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
d2.appendChild(document2.adoptNode(nodes.item(0).cloneNode(true))); //This is throwing exception
```